# How will I know the Power Efficiency of a load?

Tags: power, load, thevenin

I have a thevenin circuit with a source load. How will I get the Pin and Pout?
[image]

Comment: I know what a Thevenin equivalent is, what a source is, and what a load is.  But I've honestly never heard of a "source load".  Perhaps you could draw a schematic to clarify things?

Comment: I like my answer so I will not be modifying it. When I was in circuits class I would convert this to a norton, absorb R4 into the norton, then go to thevenin and absorb R5 since you are asking about power delivered to RL.

Comment: When you determine power flow, you need to choose the nets at which to split the circuit. Pin == Pout in most cases. Hope this helps! Now that I see you have edited your schematic, I suggest switching between norton and thevenin equivalents to absorb resistors 3, 4, and 5 into one resistor.

Comment: Theoretically you can absorb them all by just doing another thevenin but I find the brute force works better for my simple habits.

Comment: @HL-SDK. I did thevenin and norton....I just don't know the formula to use for Pin and Pout.Can you please show me in a thevenin diagram with source load the pin and pout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Thevenin equivalent is a voltage source with a resistor in series like this:

[image: Image courtesy Andy Collinson]

For power to flow you need a load which is *Rl* in this schematic. The load at which maximum power is transferred is when the load is the complex conjugate of the thevenin output impedance. If there are no reactive components, it is when the resistances of *Rth* and *Rl* are the same.

Power dissipated in load = *Vth*^2 * ( *Rl* / (*Rth* * *Rl*)^2 )

These equations come courtesy of Bucknell University. Read more [here](http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/elessonshtml/Source/Source2.html)

Comment: should I use these formula even if I am looking for the power efficiency of a load?

Comment: @HL-SDK Are you sure  "Power dissipated in source = Vth * Rth" ? Voltage times a Resistance is not a unit of Power.